# Eevee renders in gray and workbench renders in colors

Tags: eevee-render-engine, color

About render engines, when using **Workbench**, the rendered image is colorful. But when using Eevee, the rendered image is gray.

Why?

---

**Workbench render:**

[image]

---

**Eevee render**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you just set for **Viewport Render** `Color` in your mesh?

[image]

That is not how EEVEE and cycles retrieve color. They have nothing to do with final render in both render engine. It just change your viewport color which is faster and simple for easy render task. Instead of that one, you should assign a **material** to your mesh, and change the color of that shader (principled shader perhaps?). Then you will get the color in EEVEE and cycles.

[image]

Comment: Exactly! I am new to Blender, so each small detail now is important. Thanks!